# define an instance object in class inside another class

Tags: java

i created two classes, each one is in a different package ... here is the class inside the main package:

```
  package Main; 
public class Main { 
Public static void main(String [] args ) { .....} 
}
// class in main package 
class ClassS{
public int publicAtttibute;
private int pricatdAttribute;
```

And this is the second class in another package:

```
package second; 
public class ClassC{
public static void doSomething(){
ClassD ref = new ClassD(); 

} }
```

But i’m not sure if this code makes the classD and it’s attributes visible to class c, can someone please clarify it

Comment: what is `classD`?

Comment: anyway: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: ref is a local variable. It's only visible in the method doSomething().

Comment: This seems to be a question you could answer easily yourself by trying to compile the code in an IDE.

Comment: To know whether the fields in `ClassD` are accessible in `ClassC`, you need to know whether they're private, public, package-private or protected; and also whether `ClassC` and `ClassD` are in the same package.  Since you haven't shown us the code for `ClassD`, we can only guess whether the fields are accessible.  However, as jingx points out, your IDE knows!

Comment: Oh - is `ClassS` a typo?  Was that supposed to be `ClassD`?

Answer (score -1):

You defined an instance object of classD inside the classC which means that ClassD and all of it’s public attributes would NOT be visible to ClassC ..... if you want the ClassD to visibile but the attributes aren’t you could code it like this:

```
package other: 
public class ClassC{
public static void visible(){
ClassD ref = new ClassD(); 
ref.publicAttribute = 3; 
ref.privateAttribute=3; 
}}
```

Comment: Are you sure?  I don't think this is quite right.  I'm also having trouble getting your code to work.